# VB.NET CType: How do I use CType to change an object variable "obj" to my custom class that I reference using a string variable like obj.GetType.Name?

Tags: vb.net

The code below works for the class that I hard coded "XCCustomers" in my RetrieveIDandName method where I use CType. However, I would like to be able to pass in various classes and property names to get the integer and string LIST returned. For example, in my code below, I would like to also pass in "XCEmployees" to my RetrieveIDandName method. I feel so close... I was hoping someone knew how to use CType where I can pass in the class name as a string variable.

Note, all the other examples I have seen and tried fail because we are using Option Strict On which disallows late binding. That is why I need to use CType.
I also studied the "Activator.CreateInstance" code examples to try to get the class reference instance by string name but I was unable to get CType to work with that.

When I use obj.GetType.Name or obj.GetType.FullName in place of the "XCCustomers" in CType(obj, XCCustomers)(i)
I get the error "Type 'obj.GetType.Name' is not defined" or "Type 'obj.GetType.FullName' is not defined"

Thanks for your help.

Rick

```
'+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++

Imports DataLaasXC.Business

Imports DataLaasXC.Utilities

Public Class ucCustomerList


'Here is the calling method:

Public Sub CallingSub()

      Dim customerList As New XCCustomers()
      Dim customerIdAndName As New List(Of XCCustomer) = RetrieveIDandName(customerList, "CustomerId", " CustomerName")

     'This code below fails because I had to hard code “XCCustomer” in the “Dim item...” section of my RetrieveEmployeesIDandName method.
      Dim employeeList As New XCEmployees()
      Dim employeeIdAndName As New List(Of XCEmployee) = RetrieveIDandName(employeeList, "EmployeeId", " EmployeeName")

     'doing stuff here...

End Sub

'Here is the method where I would like to use the class name string when I use CType:
Private Function RetrieveIDandName(ByVal obj As Object, ByVal idPropName As String, ByVal namePropName As String) As List(Of IntStringPair) 
    Dim selectedItems As List(Of IntStringPair) = New List(Of IntStringPair)

    Dim fullyQualifiedClassName As String = obj.GetType.FullName
    Dim count As Integer = CInt(obj.GetType().GetProperty("Count").GetValue(obj, Nothing))

    If (count > 0) Then
        For i As Integer = 0 To count - 1
            'Rather than hard coding “XCCustomer” below, I want to use something like “obj.GetType.Name”???
            Dim Item As IntStringPair = New IntStringPair(CInt(CType(obj, XCCustomers)(i).GetType().GetProperty("CustomerId").GetValue(CType(obj, XCCustomers)(i), Nothing)), _
     CStr(CType(obj, XCCustomers)(i).GetType().GetProperty("CustomerName").GetValue(CType(obj, XCCustomers)(i), Nothing)))

            selectedItems.Add(Item)
        Next
    End If

    Return selectedItems
End Function

End Class
```

'+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++

' Below are the supporting classes if you need to see what else is happening:

```
Namespace DataLaasXC.Utilities

    Public Class IntStringPair
        Public Sub New(ByVal _Key As Integer, ByVal _Value As String)
            Value = _Value
            Key = _Key
        End Sub

        Public Property Value As String
        Public Property Key As Integer
    End Class
End Namespace

'+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++

Namespace DataLaasXC.Business

    Public Class XCCustomer
        Public Property CustomerId As Integer
        Public Property CustomerName As String
    End Class
End Namespace

'+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++

Namespace DataLaasXC.Business

    Public Class XCCustomers
        Inherits List(Of XCCustomer)

       Public Sub New()
           PopulateCustomersFromDatabase()
       End Sub

       Public Sub New(ByVal GetEmpty As Boolean)
       End Sub
    End Class
End Namespace

'+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++

Namespace DataLaasXC.Business

    Public Class XCEmployee
        Public Property EmployeeId As Integer
        Public Property EmployeeName As String
    End Class
End Namespace

'+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++

Namespace DataLaasXC.Business

    Public Class XCEmployees
        Inherits List(Of XCEmployee)

       Public Sub New()
           PopulateEmployeesFromDatabase()
       End Sub

       Public Sub New(ByVal GetEmpty As Boolean)
       End Sub
    End Class
End Namespace
```

Comment: Sorry, but you've posted far too much code. Boil this down until you have a couple of lines of working code - hopefully not more than 10 - that shows the error your having. Ps. By working code, obviously we mean code that would work if you weren't having this problem. Thanks.

Comment: Having `Option Strict On` is a choice. I'd say that by default it should always be on, but there can be reasons why exceptions needs to be made and it needs to be turned off. For me it's usually been when I need to do Office Automation using Late Binding. So if you think that you have a valid reason I'd suggest considering turning it off for the file(s) where this code would be, preferably with a comment explaining why it's been turned off.

Comment: @ho1 - I believe he's encountering this issue because he hasn't asked the simpler question - "how do I write this function so it can accept a `List(Of T)` for any type T?"

Comment: @Damien: Well in that case it might not be a valid reason for turning it off in this instance (I didn't read through the whole question in detail).

Comment: Thank you very much skaffman for your help on this too :)

Comment: Thank you very much Binary Worrier and ho1 for your help on this too :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since [List(Of T)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6sh2ey19.aspx) implements the non-generic IList interface, you could change your function declaration to:

```
Private Function RetrieveIDandName(ByVal obj As System.Collections.IList, ByVal idPropName As String, ByVal namePropName As String) As List(Of IntStringPair)
```

And then your troublesome line would become (with also using the property name parameters):

```
Dim Item As IntStringPair = New IntStringPair(CInt(obj(i).GetType().GetProperty(idPropName).GetValue(obj(i), Nothing)), _
CStr(obj(i).GetType().GetProperty(namePropName).GetValue(obj(i), Nothing)))
```

Of course, you could still have the first parameter by Object, and then attempt to cast to IList, but that's up to you.

Comment: Hi Damien_The_Unbeliever, Thank you for your response. I tried your code but got the error "Option Strict On disallows late binding". What would be the syntax to cast to ILIST? I tried "CType(obj, IList)(i)" but got the error on ILIST too few arguments IList. I also tried "CType(obj, IList(obj.GetType))(i)" but got the error on the second obj that array bounds cannot appear in type specifiers.

Comment: @Rick - if you're wanting to cast to IList (rather than change the function declaration, as I recommended), make sure you either have "System.Collections" in an Imports statement, or specify it fully as `System.Collections.IList`. By default in modern VB.Net, the non-generic System.Collections namespace isn't visible.

Comment: Sorry, I meant to try "CType(obj, IList(of obj.GetType))(i)" but got the error on the second obj "type 'obj.GetType' is not defined".

Comment: @Rick - stop trying to specify a type that you don't know. Use the non-generic IList interface from System.Collections. `CType(obj,System.Collections.IList)` will work. The rest of your code doesn't depend on the actual type of the objects within the list, so you don't need a more specific type.

Comment: I added Imports System.Collections.IList but got the following error: 'IList' for the Imports 'System.Collections.IList' does not refer to a Namespace, Class, Structure, Enum or Module.

Comment: @Rick - that would be because I said to import "System.Collections", not "System.Collections.IList". There is a variant of the imports statement for introducing an alias for a type, but that's not what we're trying to do here.

Comment: Wahoo!! Yeah! I Imported System.Collections and then used CType(obj,System.Collections.IList) and it works GREAT! Thanks a Million! I'm new to this site, is there some sort of super AWESOME rating I can give you?

Comment: @Rick: just upvote helpful answers. @Damien: Dude +1 for having the feckin patience of Job :)

Comment: For future readers of this answer: I only needed to do what Damien_The_Unbeliever originally stated (sorry I was spacing being it's 2am):

1) Change my ByVal obj from type object to System.Collections.IList: 
 Private Function RetrieveIDandName(ByVal obj As System.Collections.IList, ...

2) Remove my CType: 
Dim Item As IntStringPair = New IntStringPair(CInt(obj(i).GetType().GetProperty(idPropName).GetValue(obj(i), Nothing)), _
  CStr(obj(i).GetType().GetProperty(namePropName).GetValue(obj(i), Nothing)))

Answer (score 2):

From [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4x2877xb(VS.90).aspx)

> CType(expression, typename)
>   . . .
>   typename : Any expression that is legal
>   within an As clause in a Dim
>   statement, that is, the name of any
>   data type, object, structure, class,
>   or interface.

This is basically saying you can't use CType dynamically, just statically. i.e. At the point where the code is compiled the compiler needs to know what `typename` is going to be.

You can't change this at runtime.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you very much Binary Worrier for you help, yes, I was find this to be the case :)

Answer (score -1):

ctype is used to convert in object type.